# How does the function ldap_mod_add determines the entry to be modified?

Tags: php, ldap

I try to add an attribute to certain users present in an Active Directory and I have a great deal of difficulty in understanding how to be sure to add this attribute to the good user.

The documentation of PHP concerning this function indicates:

> `ldap_mod_add — Add attribute values to current attributes`
>
> `Description :`
>
> `bool ldap_mod_add ( resource $link_identifier , string $dn , array $entry )`
>
> Adds one or more attributes to the specified dn. It performs the modification at the attribute level as opposed to the object level. Object-level additions are done by the `ldap_add()` function.

And for the parameters :

> link_identifier : 
> An LDAP link identifier, returned by `ldap_connect()`.
>
> dn : 
> The distinguished name of an LDAP entity.

My being problem that the DN of a user is not a unique identifier!

Let us set for example:

> `"cn=John Jones, o=My Company, c=US"`

How to be sure that there's no other "John Jones" in the same management ?

But I noticed at the beginning of doc of the function there is :

> `ldap_mod_add — Add attribute values to current attributes`

Thus, it should be about the entry obtained with the filter?

In this case what is the utility of the parameter dn ?

Can anybody help me to understand?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The DN (Distinguished Name) must be unique.  While you might have one or more users with `cn=John Jones` values, they cannot coexist in the same container (the `o=My Company, c=US` part).

If you wished to have two users named John Jones, they could exist in different containers, but if they needed to be in the same container, then you would have had to set different CNs for at least one of them.

In some directory services other attributes need to be unique as well.  Usually, uniqueID or uid should be globally unique within the entire directory.  So you might have jjones for one, regardless of what container it is in, but the other would need to be different somehow.

Active Directory has an additional requirement that sAMAccountName be globally unique within the domain, and userPrincipalName be unique within the forest.

Usually the directory will fail with an error when you try to create a second user with the same full DN or move a user with a conflicting naming attribute into a container.  Each directory will have different error codes for these cases.

Comment: Hi geoffc and thanks for your answer,

I understand that DN must be unique and I would like it to be unique, but when I display the DN there's no field witch permit me to distingate the one from the other...

How can I introduce another element in the displayed DN?

I have some unique identifiers like objectguid (global userID) but I can't find it in the DN.

is there a file to modify in the active directory to choose what I want to find in the DN?

I can't find as well how to display uid in the DN.

Comment: @Alexdezark DN is set at create time.  The only modification allowed is a rename.  ldap_modrdn is the rename op.  Depending on the backend directory, and the specific object class, the naming attribute may differ.  For example, all of the following are valid name attributes (or RDN's, Relative DN's) `uid=geoffc` or `cn=geoffc` or `acmeMyUserClassNamingAttr=geoffc` if your schema so defines them.  CN and Uid are most common.  AD, eDir use CN=.  OpenLDAP, SunOne, usually use uid=.  But none is more correct than any other.